# Dictionary error :"TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment"

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to make a phonebook that saves to file in python. here is the snippet of code with the problem:

```
import os

f = open("save")
forbidden = f.readline()
forbiddens = f.readline()
dictionary = f.readline()
stop = 0
global arguments
print("phonebook os by me")

def write():
    global forbidden
    global forbiddens
    global dictionary
    f = open("save")
    f.write(forbidden and '\n' and forbiddens and '\n' and dictionary)
    f.close()

def add_cc():
    global forbidden
    global dictionary
    global arguments
    name = arguments[1]
    number = int(arguments[2])
    if name in forbidden:
        print("403: forbidden!")
    elif name in dictionary:
        print("406: Not acceptable! This item is already in the dictionary!")
    else:
        dictionary[name] = number
    write()
    start()

def del_cc():
    global arguments
    global dictionary
    name = arguments[1]
    del dictionary[name]
    write()
    start()

def get_cc():
    global arguments
    global forbidden
    global dictionary
    name = arguments[1]
    if name in dictionary:
        print(dictionary[name])
    elif name in forbidden:
        print("403: Forbidden!")
    else:
        print("404: Item not Found.")
    start()
```

(rest is too long)

The problem comes at  `dictionary[name] = number` line 12. the error i get is

```
    dictionary[name] = number
TypeError: 'str' object does not support item assignment
```

can someone help me?

Comment: Where does dictionary get created? It looks like somewhere it is getting reassigned to a string (or maybe initialized as a string). Try `print(dictionary)` right before line 12 to see what it is.

Comment: it was         `{}`      not        `"{}"`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can help you :) .

Check in your code for assignment to `dictionary`. The variable `dictionary` isn't a dictionary, but a string, so somewhere in your code will be something like:

```
dictionary = " evaluates to string "
```

or equivalent to it.

This above you already know from the error message, but it seems not to help you to know what to do to avoid the error. So here how you have to change your code, so that the error is gone:

```
import os

f = open("save")
forbidden = f.readline()
forbiddens = f.readline()
```

> `dictionary = {} # now it is a dictionary not a string "{}"`

Comment: the whole code, (if you want to see it is) up there

Comment: also the text document reads    `{}` (new line)    `[]` (new line)    '{}'